# My view dont recieve data from my Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I will just show the part of the code I am having problens. If you think that you need to see all the code, let me know.

My Controller:

```
index: function() {
    var documents = new App.Collections.Documents();
    documents.fetch({
        success: function() {
            new App.Views.Index({ collection: documents });
        },
        error: function() {
            new Error({ message: "Error loading documents." });
        }
    });
},
```

My View:

```
App.Views.Index = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log(this.documents);
        this.documents = this.options.documents;
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        if(this.documents.length > 0) {
            var out = "<h3><a href='#new'>Create New</a></h3><ul>";
            _(this.documents).each(function(item) {
                out += "<li><a href='#documents/" + item.id + "'>" + item.escape('title') + "</a></li>";
            });
            out += "</ul>";
        } else {
            out = "<h3>No documents! <a href='#new'>Create one</a></h3>";
        }
        $(this.el).html(out);
        $('#app').html(this.el);
    }
});
```

The console.log of document code is: undefined
In the controller, **var document** is valid.

WHYYyY? How I can Access the json sent by the Controller in the view?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(this.documents);`

`this.documents = this.options.documents;`

Your using console.log before `this.documents` is even set.

UPDATE:

`new App.Views.Index({ collection: documents });`

`this.documents = this.options.documents;`

Wouldn't it be `this.documents = this.options.collection;` ? Because I don't see you passing the option.documents variable anywhere.

Comment: No, any collection option is available automatically on the view object. See http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-110

Comment: @dira Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see the variable `this.documents` defined anywhere else. I can understand how it would be accessible when extending Backbone.View, but the variable name being used is `collection` not `documents`

Comment: Yes Leo, you are right, this.collection should work, not this.documents or this.options.documents. Great observation.

Answer (score 1):

You pass `collection: documents`, so in your view you access it with `this.collection`.

Check out this jsfiddle that shows it working: http://jsfiddle.net/dira/TZZnA/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know backbone too well ... but is `this.documents` defined before entering the initialize function ? seems not to be - try switching around the lines :

```
this.documents = this.options.documents; // define the variable
console.log(this.documents); // console log it
```

Comment: Your comment is write, but I still having the same issue. The log of this is undefined.

Comment: var documents = new App.Collections.Documents(); in the controller is a local variable - as I said I really dont know backbone but that seems incorrect to me ... have a look at how you pass data between controller and view